# how to update model from a list of documents to an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a MongoDB instance with a collection of users that is something like this:

```
{
        "Username": "Amin-AMD",
        "FriendsList": [
            {
                "UserId": "5e076f4b19e8cd000162c962",
                "NickName": "Amin-Mobile",
                "ClanName": null,
                "ClanId": null,
                "Level": NumberInt(1),
                "ActiveCosmeticItems": [
                    "hair0",
                    "skin0",
                    "eye0",
                    "mouth0",
                    "daub0",
                    "acc"
                ],
                "IsOnline": false
            },
            {
                "UserId": "5e08a4a119e8cd000167929e",
                "NickName": "saeed",
                "ClanName": null,
                "ClanId": null,
                "Level": NumberInt(7),
                "ActiveCosmeticItems": [
                    "hair5",
                    "skin2",
                    "eye2",
                    "mouth10",
                    "daub0",
                    "acc0"
                ],
                "IsOnline": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

As shown above, I have embedded a list of Friends in our User's collection. but for a reason, we need to change this model to reference Friends. So I need to write a query to replace the whole FriendModel with just a `UserId`.

I have reached to this query but it throws an exception.

```
db.Users.updateMany({ "FriendsList" : { $ne : [] }}, { $set : { "FriendsList.$" : "FriendsList.$.UserId" }})
```

In fact, for each friend, I just need the `UserId` so the new `FriendsList` will be an array and it should be something like this:

```
{
        "Username": "Amin-AMD",
        "FriendsList": [
            "5e076f4b19e8cd000162c962",                
            "5e08a4a119e8cd000167929e"
        ]
    }
```

MongoDB version: **4.2.1**

Comment: What MongoDB version ?

Comment: My MongoDB version 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps :

1. **Update existing data in DB :**

   As you can use aggregation pipeline in updates starting MongoDB version `4.2`.

**Query to update data :**

```
db.collection.updateMany({ "FriendsList" : { $ne : [] }},[{$set :{FriendsList: '$FriendsList.UserId'}}])
```

But if your `FriendsList.UserId` are strings better convert them to `ObjectId()` as like below :

```
db.colleciton.updateMany({ "FriendsList" : { $ne : [] }},[{$set :{FriendsList: { $map: { input: '$FriendsList.UserId', in: {$toObjectId: '$$this'}} }}}])
```

2. **Update existing mongoose model to restrict future writes on DB :**

**Mongoose Model :**

So `FriendsList` will be an array of `ObjectId()`'s which will be referred to another new schema via `ref` field.

```
FriendsList:[{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "FriendList" /** 'FriendList' will be a mongoose schema refers to a collection */
}]
```

**Ref :** [mongoose-populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Is mongoose a MongoDB feature or it's a framework? cause I'm using dotnet core and MongoDb C# driver to connect to db.

Comment: If I use the `ref` can the `FriendsList` be lazy-loaded?

Comment: @AminSojoudi : Oh my bad when I say word `model` in your question defaults to `mongoose` yes mongoose is a node ode library to connect to MongoDB..

Comment: @AminSojoudi : Not sure how models work in `MongoDb C# driver` but for mongoose all models are loaded at the beginning..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `User` model

```
FriendsList:{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "FriendList"    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you trying to say. can you explain more?